# What's the different between (Type) and Get.Type()

Tags: c#, ninject

Why are these both different when called on same object?

```
protected override Type GetType(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
{
    var typeOne = (Type)arugments.Single();
    Debug.WriteLine(typeOne.ToString()); // This gives me NewWorld.OldWorld.Class

    var typeTwo = arugments.Single().GetType();
    Debug.WriteLine(typeTwo.ToString()); // This gives me System.RuntimeType

    return typeOne;
}
```

Comment: `(Type)` is a cast; `GetType()` is a method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to get *really* meta...

Assuming your `arguments` is actually an array of `Type`s, the expression `(Type)arguments.Single()` makes the compile-time type of the single argument become `Type`.

The type `Type` represents a type. In this case, you got `NewWorld.OldWorld.Class`, which most likely is the fully qualified name of a class. The single element in `arguments` (which is of type `Type`) represents the type `NewWord.OldWorld.Class`.

The second expression in question, `arguments.Single().GetType()` gets the runtime type of the object on which `GetType` is called, as an instance of `Type`. In this case, This will return the runtime type of `arguments.Single()`, which is `RuntimeType`, a subclass of `Type`.

Basically:

- `(Type)arguments.Single()` tells the compiler that `arguments` contains a single element that is of type `Type`. It evaluates to a `Type` object that represents `NewWord.OldWord.Class`.
- `arguments.Single().GetType()` gets the *type* of `argument.Single()`. This is *not* the same as what type `arguments.Single()` represents. It *represents* the type `Class`, but its *type* is `RuntimeType`. If you are still confused, here's an example with integers.

  ```
  int[] array = new int[] { 10 };
  ```

  `array.Single()` *represents* the number 10 but its *type* is `System.Int32`.

Comment: yes I was passing array of `Type` and calling `GetType()` on `Type` gave `System.RuntimeType`.